# How to simplifly pull and push? I don't want to type "origin master" anymore

Tags: git

Some times, when trying to run `$ git pull`, git used to say that I needed to be more specific (ie. add "origin master"). So then I found here on stackoverflow that I could run these and forget about it:

```
$ git config --global branch.master.remote origin
$ git config --global branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

And it works. But now it won't let me push! It says:

```
fatal: The current branch master has multiple upstream branches, refusing to push.
```

So what should I do if I want to be able to run "git pull" for pulling, and "git push" for pushing? No tricks this time please! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be a simple matter of setting your branch to the correct upstream branch, then pushing/pulling at will.

```
git checkout master # If not already on master
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
git push
git pull
```

Using any of the `git config` options for this is not necessary, and actually may be more problematic than it's worth.

To ensure that you're only pushing the branch you're on, you *would* want to add this to your configuration:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Comment: Does the upstream stay configured correctly after switching branches? Let's say I clone a repo, set the upstream, then work on other branches, and then come back to master again. Will git push and pull work?

Comment: Yes.  You can verify this by typing `git branch -vv`, which will show a column with your local branch name, its latest commit SHA, what remote branch it's pointing to if any, and the last commit message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git version 2.0.X and above it will be the default behaviour for all the new branches that you checkout.

for all the branches that you have chcekedout prior to that you will need to set the upstream/downstream manually .

Read [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt) the first paragraph to get more information.